Yocto recipe that changes based on image paramaters
I'm trying to add a feature to a development image that lets me boot from an sdcard, and I don't want this feature installed on the production image.
I was trying to do this as an IMAGE_FEATURE but yocto doesn't recognize this as a valid image feature.
#in image.bb

require base-image.bb

IMAGE_FEATURES:append = "sd-card-boot"

# u-boot-distro-boot.bbappend

SRC_URI:append:sd-card-boot = " \
    file://sd-card-boot/uEnv-sd-boot.txt.in \
"

do_compile:prepend:sd-card-boot() {
   cat ${WORKDIR}/uEnv-sd-card-boot.txt.in >> ${S}/uEnv.txt.in
}


I've tried a number of different things in my image.bb
export SD_CARD_BOOT = "1" # doesn't show up in environment
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " sd-card-boot " # doesn't show up in distro features

There has to be some way I can pass some sort of variable or setting from my image file to a bbappend...
-------------- UPDATE ---------------------
Well... I found a method.  It's not the most delicious, but it works I guess...
create conf/distro/my-distro.conf
# mydistro.conf
require conf/distro/supplier-distro.inc

SD_CARD_BOOT = "true"

In the recipe file I just changed it to
do_compile:prepend:() {
   if [ "${SD_CARD_BOOT}" = "true" ]; then
      cat ${WORKDIR}/uEnv-sd-card-boot.txt.in >> ${S}/uEnv.txt.in
   fi
}


